# What Wordpress Function can I use for A search query like this?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to output the URL value from my database base on the "Area".

```
$the_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `URL`FROM  `wp_nearby_locations` WHERE  `Area` =  'Area Name'");
```

Do you know what function I can use for this? `$wpdb->get_results` don't work.

Comment: "don't work" is, unfortunately, not nearly enough information for us to help you.  What happens, exactly? Do you get an error? Do you get an empty recordset? How are you retrieving the recordset? Have you read this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query#The_Revised_Loop

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your SQL Query,
Use this code to see error.

```
$the_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `URL`FROM  `wp_nearby_locations` WHERE  `Area` =  'Area Name'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Here is corrected SQL Query and should look like

```
"SELECT `URL` FROM  `wp_nearby_locations` WHERE  `Area` =  'Area Name'"
```

There should be space between 'URL'FROM